# A screen leading to another screen with navigation bar

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-application

im pretty new to Flutter
Im trying to make a login page called unAuthPage and after logging in it will show the homepage with navigation bar called AuthPage ,,
For now the login Authentication is just a Boolean Var called Auth ,,
I tried making the bool false at first = not logged in , and show login page
in Login page if you click an image there's onTap that makes the auth bool true
but i can't call the authpage ,,
This is my code if someone could help it would make me so happy :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './joinedGroups.dart';
import './searchCommunity.dart';
import './login.dart';
import './profile.dart';
import './settings.dart';
 bool auth=false;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());



class MyApp extends  StatefulWidget  {



  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    print("inMyApp");

    return auth? authPage() : unAuthPage() ;
    }

}


// ignore: camel_case_types
class authPage extends  State<MyApp>{

  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
   eventsPage(),
    eventsPage(),
   savedEventsPage(),
    profilePage(),
   settingsPage(),



  ];



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("inAuthPage");
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Center( child: Text('Saudi Events')),
        ),
        body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
             type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index){
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;

            });
          },

          iconSize: 30.0,
          items: [

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.language),
          title: Text('')
        ),





                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group),
            title: Text('')

          ) ,
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            title: Text('')

          ) ,

            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                title: Text('')

            ) ,
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('true')


          ) ,
          ] ,

        ),

       ),

    );
  }




}

class unAuthPage extends State<MyApp>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(

          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Hopin',

              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "CaesarDresser",
                  color: Colors.blueGrey
              ),

            ),

            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[50],
          ),
          body:

          Container(


            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

              children: <Widget>[

                Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),


                Text('Weolcome to Hopin',

                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "CaesarDresser",
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,

                  ),
                ),

                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Tapped");
                  main();

                  },

                  child: Container(


                    width: 260.0,
                    height: 60,

                    decoration: BoxDecoration(


                      image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/google_signin_button.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,


                      ),


                    ),


                  ),

                )


              ],

            ),

          ),

        )
    );

  }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just go to login page then you can use in onTap like this,

```
onTap: (){
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourNextScreen()),
  );
}
```

or you can use setState() to make your variable false to true

and why are you calling main() in onTap?